# Design Patterns- Multiple Observer

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am new to design patterns. I am writing a piece of code where there is one subject and multiple observers. Both subject and observers have interfaces. So say if I have 5 observers, do I need to create 5 different interfaces with their separate update methods? Or should I create just one interface and write five update methods for all observers?

Answer (score 4):

Often you will need just one observer interface that all 5 observer classes can implement. What will differ will be how the observers react to the notification of change. Whether this applies to you will depend completely on your program structure and needs.

Note that observers that share a single interface can also listen for different changes in the observed, but still use the same interface. For example if you used a PropertyChangeListener as your observer interface, you could base what you listen to by checking the propertyName returned in the PropertyChangeEvent that is passed to your observer.

Note however that if what the observers are listening to are very different, then yes, they might need a unique interface. Using a Swing example, since that is what I'm most knowledgeable in, there are many different listener classes and interfaces available, including ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ... all though derived from a common super interface, EventListener. Note that all pass a parameter to their listeners that is based on a common super class, the AWTEvent class.

For better more specific help, please consider giving us more specifics of your problem.

Comment: Yes, but only if the event is the same. If you're observing five completely unrelated things, I'd have five interfaces.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: true sometimes, but not necessarily. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to create 5 different interface with their seperate update methods? Or I should just create one interface and write five update methods for all observers?

One interface with five update methods seems much less cohesive than five different interfaces. However, you say you only have one kind of subject (which is the *client* to the Observers). But it depends on how cohesive is this client.

The [interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) likely applies here to help you decide. If you provide more details, I could give more opinions.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Java EE, I would suggest using topics and subscribers using JMS... It is more robust. I don't know what kind of solution you are looking for but it would be more robust if you need to persist and prevent from losing data...

Don't hesitate if you need something.